# SwingWorker hangs at Unsafe.park()

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

I have a `SwingWorker` that communicates with a server in the background and then updates a `JFrame`. I was debugging my app and noticed that even after the `SwingWorker` finished its work, its thread still remained. It is hanging at `Unsafe.park(java.lang.Object)` which is a native method. I looked in to this further and found that all my other `SwingWorker`s in my app do the same thing after they finish. I can provide source code if someone wants it but I don't think it is necessary because the problem seems to be very general.

#### Update

I ran the app without the debugger and the problem is still happening. This is the dump of the `SwingWorker` thread:

```
"SwingWorker-pool-2-thread-1" daemon prio=6 tid=0x03219800 nid=0xd74 waiting on
condition [0x04b7f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x22ec63d8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.Abstra
ctQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject
.await(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I made a sample program that uses `SwingWorker` the way it is normally used in a application. This program has the same problem. Here is the code:

```
package swingworkerlocktest;

import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class SwingWorkerLockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Frame");
        final JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea(4, 20);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(outputArea);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        (new SwingWorker<Object, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
                publish("Background task.");
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                for (String str : chunks) {
                    outputArea.append(str + "\n");
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void done() {
                outputArea.append("Background task finished.");
            }
        }).execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393139/deadlock-in-threadpoolexecutor

Comment: @RobKielty I have seen a similar post elsewhere. That one relates to Java 6, I have Java 7, so I would think it would be fixed by now. I would rather not have to edit the OpenJDK source code. I was hoping there was another solution.

Comment: It would be worth checking that the bug is fixed or not fixed. It could well be that you have exposed another bug. Can you post sample code to reproduces the problem that you encounter?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9802415/230513) related?

Comment: Does this problem manifest when you are NOT debugging your application?  (You should be able to check by sending a frozen application the relevant signal to get it to produce a thread dump to the console.)

Comment: @StephenC This problem still happens when I am not debugging. I added the thread dump (not from the debugger) to my question.

Comment: @RobKielty I added source code for a sample application with this problem to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal behavior of SwingWorker, the Thread should terminate after 10 minutes if it is idle. It's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156898/why-do-my-swingworker-threads-keep-running-even-though-they-are-done-executing)

Comment: This seems to be the answer, and seems to be logical behavior. At this point though, I don't even remember why I asked this question, nor why I didn't like the worker threads hanging around in the background.